# Storing CF7 submissions as PHP Variables which can then be used on the front-end?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, contact-form-7

Just wondering if anyone can help, I've hit a wall with this and been looking for a solution for the past 5 hours.

I have my CF7 form set up and I'm using the following function to set all my fields as variables and then show them in the error log. It works well:

```html
function calculator_quote($contact_form){
  $title = $contact_form->title();

  if($title === 'Online Calculator'){
      $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();

      if($submission){
          $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();

          $cf7_fuel = $posted_data['fuel-quantity'];
          $cf7_postcode = $posted_data['your-postcode'];
          $cf7_delivery = $posted_data['delivery-type'];
          $cf7_tanker = $posted_data['tanker-type'];
          $cf7_email = $posted_data['your-email'];

          ob_start();
          var_dump($posted_data);
          error_log(ob_get_clean());
      }
  }
}

add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'calculator_quote' );
```

However, I now need to access these variables on the front-end to run some calculations (I have global ACF fields set up and I need to run some simple PHP sums and comparison queries with what is sent in the form). I understand that CF7 submissions are sent as AJAX but I have limited knowledge on how best to extract them and display them. I don't need them stored, just outputting and visible beneath the form.

Any guidance on how best to approach this would be most appreciated.

Comment: if you aren't reloading the page you will need to use JavaScript to do this.

Comment: Ok thank you, can you suggest any guidance or documentation on the best way to go about this?

Comment: `However, I now need to access these variables on the front-end to run some calculations` - can you elaborate on this?  Please update your question.

Comment: What about these ACF fields?  How would your formulas work, and where do you expect to show your updated output?  Your question is still a little vague.

Answer (score 0):

Have your function return the post data

```
<?php

function calculator_quote($contact_form){
  $title = $contact_form->title();

  if($title === 'Online Calculator'){
      $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();

      if($submission){
          $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();
          $array = [];
          $cf7_fuel = $posted_data['fuel-quantity'];
          $cf7_postcode = $posted_data['your-postcode'];
          $cf7_delivery = $posted_data['delivery-type'];
          $cf7_tanker = $posted_data['tanker-type'];
          $cf7_email = $posted_data['your-email'];
          array_push($array, $cf7_fuel, $cf7_postcode, $cf7_delivery, $cf7_tanker, $cf7_email);

          ob_start();
          var_dump($posted_data);
          error_log(ob_get_clean());

          return json_encode($array);
      }
  }
  return false;
}

add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'calculator_quote' );
?>
```

then under your form display it on the front-end

```
<script>
var formData = <?php do_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail' ); ?>;

// display value in the browser
document.write(formData);
</script>
```

Comment: This won't work. The hook `wpcf7_before_send_mail` does not return anything.

Comment: It will if you modify `calculator_quote()` function to return values. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/144801/return-a-custom-value-in-a-function-added-to-an-action-hook

Comment: Have you tested your result?

Comment: Thank you for this. I've updated my question with more details on what needs to be done with the submission data. I ran your code and get the following error: "The response is not a valid JSON response."

Comment: @MelissaShephard, make sure you format your data to be valid json. You can use `json_encode()` to encode an array. Use array_push() to create an array with the post values.

Comment: @MelissaShephard, I updated the answers with `json_encode`